# Need to use saxon for transforming html to xml using xslt

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

I am converting html to xml using xslt1.0. I want to migrate to xslt2.0 for some built-in functions. Currently my transformation code is like,

```
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
```

and method for conversion is

```
public static String convert(String inputHtml, String xsl) throws Exception {
        File xsltFile = new File(xsl);

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputHtml.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        javax.xml.transform.Source xmlSource = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(is);
        javax.xml.transform.Source xsltSource = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(xsltFile);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        javax.xml.transform.Result result = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(sw);

        javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory transFact = javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        javax.xml.transform.Transformer trans = transFact.newTransformer(xsltSource);

        trans.transform(xmlSource, result);
        return sw.getBuffer().toString();
    }
```

How to write for saxon processor?. Thanks in advance

Comment: well, the differences from xslt1.0 to xslt2.0 would be in the xsl file, not in the java code.

Comment: Did you mean that we can change the version of xsl file from 1.0 to 2.0?.

Answer (score 1):

The Java code doesn't need to change: if Saxon9.3 is on the classpath, it should load it and use it automatically. But if you want to be 100% confident that Saxon gets loaded (which is probably a good idea if the code uses XSLT 2.0 or Saxon extensions) then change the line

```
TransformerFactory transFact javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance();
```

to

```
TransformerFactory transFact = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
```

Comment: Incidentally, I would be inclined to wrap the HTML string in a StringReader and pass this to the InputSource, rather than going via a ByteArrayInputStream.

Comment: Its working when my inputs are xml and xslt to transform into html, But when my inputs are html and xslt to transform into xml, its showing error like
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.setContentHandler(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.saxon.PreparedStylesheet.loadStylesheetModule(PreparedStylesheet.java:261)
at net.sf.saxon.PreparedStylesheet.prepare(PreparedStylesheet.java:185)
at 
net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:132)
at net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:87)